# How to check region size in hbase via java code

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

My HBase table is split into 10 different regions. I want to check via Java code if a region contains any data, or what is the size of each region.

I see `HRegionLocation`, `HRegionInfo` doesn't have such direct function to get the size of a region.

Has anyone come across such requirement?

Answer (score 1):

This info is available from [`RegionMetrics.getStoreFileSize()`](https://hbase.apache.org/2.1/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/RegionMetrics.html#getStoreFileSize--), along with all other region stats in `RegionMetrics`.
You can go through a long chain of calls like this to get there:
`Connection` > `getAdmin()` > `getClusterMetrics()` > `getLiveServerMetrics()` > `getRegionMetrics()`.